# jmeter performance testing and load testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am performing performance and load testing by sending 1000 requests to the HTTPS sampler, with a ramp-up period of 1 second or a loop count of 3. Sometimes, my requests fail or I get an error.

please share details about it what is and why its happening?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Error" is too broad, we cannot tell you why it's happening without knowing the error details.

The most common reasons are:

1. Your application gets overloaded and cannot properly respond to the incoming requests fired by JMeter. In order to get the reason you can:

   - check your application logs for any suspicious entries
   - ensure that your application under test has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. It can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)
   - rerun your test with a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) telemetry enabled, this way you will get in-depth view on what's going on under the hood and which component is responsible for slow responses or returning the error so the component could be optimized or fixed
2. JMeter is not properly configured for high loads, default configuration is okay for tests development and/or debugging but it might not be sufficient for real load test

   - make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools)
   - like for the application under test make sure that your load generator machine has enough CPU, RAM, etc.
   - you might need to switch to [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html) mode if a single load generator machine is not sufficient for conducting the required load

Comment: Thank you for providing the information.